# Run an existing python web application inside a virtalenv

Tags: python, windows, directory, project, virtualenv

I am new to python development using virtualenv. I have installed python 2.7, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper in windows and I am using windows PS. I have referred lots of tutorials for setting  this up. Most of them contained the same steps and almost all of them stopped short of explaining what to do *after* the virtualenv was created.

1. How do I actually work in a virtualenv? suppose I want to create a new flask application after installing that package in my new env virtualenv (eg; testenv).
2. If I already have an existing project and I want to put it inside a newly created virtual env, how do I do that? How should the folder structure be like?
3. My understanding of virtual env is that it provides a sandbox for your application by isolating it and keeping all its dependencies to itself in that particular env (and not sharing and it with others). Have I understood it wrong?

Please help me clear this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I actually work in a virtualenv? suppose I want to create a new flask application after installing that package in my new env virtualenv (eg; testenv).

You open up Command Prompt and activate the virtualenv:

```
> \path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

When you run `python` and `pip`, they run in the virtualenv. You have to do this for every Command Prompt window, since working in a virtualenv is really just running `C:\path\to\env\bin\python` instead of just `python` and `C:\path\to\env\bin\pip` instead of `pip`.

> If I already have an existing project and I want to put it inside a newly created virtual env, how do I do that? How should the folder structure be like?

It doesn't matter. When you install Python packages, they get installed globally into `C:\Python27\site-packages`. With virtualenv, you can create isolated Python environments that have their own packages, so if you're working on two projects that require different versions of a package, they can coexist without any issues.

Some people make a folder for their virtualenvs (like `C:\Users\you\Virtualenvs\my_website`). You can also store it with your project (like `C:\Users\you\Projects\my_website\venv`). Once you activate it, the location doesn't matter. I use the latter.

> My understanding of virtual env is that it provides a sandbox for your application by isolating it and keeping all its dependencies to itself in that particular env (and not sharing and it with others). Have I understood it wrong?

Nope. The only point that I would clarify is that the "sandbox" is only for Python's packages, it doesn't affect your application in any way.

Answer (score 0):

1. testenv/bin/pip and testenv/bin/python
2. I'd check it in a local repository and check it out in the virtualenv.
3. No, you have not.